# Are funny chars in hash keys browser safe?

Tags: javascript, browser, hash

As far as I can tell all chars that are legal in strings can be used in hash keys too, but does anyone know if this is the case in javascript in all major browsers too?

I'm using the danish chars 'æøå' in some hash keys, and it seems to work fine in all the browsers I have tested it on (but unfortunately my collection of browsers is incomplete).

Comment: **Funny** chars? Anyway if you store your hash as string (?!)...why not?

Comment: It is probably ok, I just wanted to be sure not to have overlooked some quirks in some old version browser that would make my program crash. Maybe if some old browsers javascript didn't support utf-8 strings or something like that? :-/

Comment: BTW I found out that I really don't need to use them anyway in my program (for some other unrelated reasons), so luckily it has turned into an academic discussion. ;-)

Comment: UTF-8 is (more or less) well supported even in IE6, I don't think you'll ever have to work with a browser that doesn't support it